# Can you reset who appears when you search on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I know Facebook uses complex heuristics to determine who your "best" friends are and thus they move higher up the list of people when you type certain letters into the search bar- for instance, 's' would yield Sarah, Sam, and Stephen in the order of how much i interact with them.

However, my younger sister has been using my (generally idle) facebook to interact with some of her friends for several months. Now she has her own facebook, and I've begun using facebook more myself, but her friends show up above mine in the search bar.

Is there any way to reset the data collection? They aren't my "best" friends, and I feel creepy seeing the profiles of girls several years younger than I showing up all the time. I just want to start anew so MY friends will be the first results.

Comment: I guess unfriending them will prove more effective. Not sure though!

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't. Just keep on using your account as normal, and hopefully those suggestions will go away in few weeks. You can also tell facebook that they are not in your frind circle by clicking on "x" on suggested profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Long time from that question, hope this can help somebody...
Once I've deactivated my account and after a week (when I reactivate it) the search results were reseted. So here is where you must be careful with the first search you do. Well, it's not an orthodox method but worked.

Comment: could you show an example of before & after?